# How to listen to printing jobs in java

Tags: java, printing

I want to know how to see get the printing details which any other application (Word, Excel, PDF readers) sent to the printer in a Java application. That means, the user send various types of  documents to printers from one PC.

My Java application must count how many documents sent to printers.

How can I get these details in a Java SE application? Any resource, useful link, guidance highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be directly done using Java but there is a workaround.

For each print job there are two spool files generated by the Windows spooler service.

One file with the `.SHD` extension for job settings, and one with the `.SPL` extension for the drawing commands.

These files could be stored in a user defined location on a per-printer basis. The default location for all spooler jobs is `c:\windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS`.

**To set location on a per-printer basis**

1. Click Start, click Run, type `regedit` in the open box, and then click
   OK.
2. Locate the following registry subkey, where `<printername>` is the
   name of your printer:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
       NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers\

   In the right pane,
   right-click `SpoolDirectory`, and then click Modify.
3. In the Value data box, type the location where you want the spool files to be stored.
   For example, type `c:\windows\system32\spool\printers` as the default
   location.
4. Quit Registry Editor. Restart the Print Spooler service.

All new jobs will be of the form `XXXXX.SPL` and `XXXXX.SHD` and will be numbered consistently with their JobIDs.

Using Java you could monitor this folder for new jobs being sent to the printer service or to a particular printer.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr John.As you mentioned there is a folder.Would you explain more?I want to know, is one .SHD file created for each print?(Ex.to print one document,one .SHD file) and how long this files exist?( till the command sent to the printer?,I looked up in my folder,but it was empty eventhough I ve printed ealier)if it is so, should we have to always looking at this folder and count these files? Also if there are more printers, how can we identify which printer belongs to which .SHD?(Does the jobid number has which printer's job is going to print?)

Comment: One the print job is completed, these files get cleared. I haven't worked on this before, it's an idea that came to my mind.

Comment: you mentioned 'once the print job is completed,these files get cleared..' if the printer takes 4 seconds to print, a .SHD file may remain for 4 seconds? or just send the command,create .SHD file and delete .SHD file?if it is so, we wont' be able to catch .SHD?(eventhough in a thread while(true){counting files in the folder by java code...} may not give a good result in case there is an slowness in jdk grab the files in the folder?) any way your idea is excellent.Thanks again for it. :)

Comment: Maybe you could bring JNI in and use Print Spooler API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff686807(v=vs.85).aspx)